# Почему ошибка? printf() пишет bad_ptr

Tags: массивы, c++

Есть:

```
void put_in_mass(char *str, char *mass, int pos)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        mass[pos * 256 + i] = str[i];
    }
}
```

и в main():

```
char mass[1024][256];
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    put_in_mass(buff, &mass[0][0], i);
    printf("%s", mass[i][0]);
}
```

printf() пишет bad_ptr. В buff правда несколько раз встречается '0' (символ завершения строки), в этом ли причина?

Comment: Скобки не забыли?  

    for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) {
      put_in_mass(buff, &mass[0][0], i);
      printf("%s",mass[i][0]);
    }

Comment: Ильдар, не забыл, просто когда сюда копировал забыл добавить.

Comment: Где объявлена `buff`, как заполняется?

Comment: Вместо printf("%s", mass[i][0]); надо printf("%s", &mass[i][0]);

--

Собственно, @mikillskegg уже написал это, только непонято почему обсуждение продолжается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mass[i][0] - это собственно переменная char, т.е. элемент N 0 строки i. Чтобы получить адрес всей строки, пишите

```
printf("%s",mass[i]);
```

или

```
printf("%s",&mass[i][0]);
```

Только удостоверьтесь, что строка заканчивается нулем и перед ним нет непечатаемых символов, а то может напечататься ерунда всякая.

Comment: Вот содержимое mass[i] из дебага в момент запроса на нулевой итерации:
аангич s. m. the winter duck. ННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННННН
заканчивается сие чудо '\0' естественно.
Чуть тока жму F10 на следующей итерации сразу такое:
Unhandled exception at 0x1029984f (msvcr90d.dll) in SeregaProject2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffe0.

Comment: Что-то у Вас с алгоритмом заполнения буфера. Продумайте всю программу еще раз.